# Rss feed of Active Directory Changes?

Tags: active-directory

Is it possible to setup a RSS feed to view all changes made to an Active Directory database?

Comment: Not finding much information on this. I have found a program that will send an e-mail with every change. Currently investigating the possibility of creating an application to convert the e-mails into a RSS format.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Quest Active Directory PowerShell extensions you can easily enough query for all the new/changed users, computers, etc.

Comment: Quest is the tool of choice around here as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are products which monitor/audit AD changes, however they are expensive enterprise-level products, which will typically require a SQL backend and significant storage.

As mrdenny said, this can be done programmatically (in any language with AD/LDAP hooks) and present the output in xml format. (RSS is essentially an xml document containing a directory listing of articles.)

If you have a serious need to do auditing, I recommend beginning with a search for "Active Directory Change Auditing", otherwise I'd stick to a scripted solution.  [Microsoft's Technet Script Center Repository](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us) has a lot of code that people have offered for free to get you started.